# Weak reference in Firefox JavaScript chrome code

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Suppose I'm writing a class `A` **in my Jetpack-based library (i.e. we're talking about chrome/extension code)**:

```
function A() {
  //constructor
}
A.prototype = {
  //class members
};
```

The user creates an instance of class `A`:

```
var a = new A();
```

now suppose I want to keep track of all the instances of `A` that were created, I could do:

```
var listA = [];
```

and add `listA.push(this);` in the constructor of `A`, ending up with:

```
var listA = [];

function A() {
  // constructor
  listA.push(this);
}

A.prototype = {
  // class members
};
```

all is fine, until the user of `a` drops its reference (e.g. `a` goes out of scope). I have now a problem: `listA` still contains a reference to `a` so it will never be garbage collected. Moreover I have no way to filter out of `listA` instances of `A` that are otherwise unreachable. I'm effectively leaking memory.

What I'd need is to push to `listA` weak references instead of regular ones. I think it is possible to do it somehow, but I don't really know where to go from here. I can envision something like:

```
var weak_a = new weakRef(a);
assert(weak_a.ref === a);
```

But then I don't know, for example, how to test if a weak reference is still valid. Or how to efficiently filter out dead weak entries in `listA`. Any suggestions?

Comment: so... listA is a member of a?

Comment: nope. I edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make your class [indicate it supports weak references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Weak_reference).  Then, when you want to use the weak reference version of it, you'll want to use [`Components.utils.getWeakReference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.getWeakReference) and store that.  [Here is some test code](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/xpconnect/tests/unit/test_js_weak_references.js) that shows you how to use it more in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! That's precisely what I was looking for. Do you happen also to have some word of advice on how to do the array bookkeeping part of the question (i.e. efficiently removing items from the array when they are recalimed by GC)? Is there some callback I can exploit that is executed when a weak reference becomes invalid?

Comment: No callback that I'm aware of.  You'll just have to iterate it every so often with `Array.filter` and remove the null entries.  May be faster to use a hash table too.

Comment: What if nsXPCOMCycleCollectionParticipant was scriptable? I could overload ::Unlink() and use it as some sort of automatic destructor...

Comment: There's no way that would be made scriptable ;)

Comment: Could you please add the code? I'm a beginner and I don't understand the MDN page.